# Mobile stylesheet not showing

Tags: iphone, css, mobile

I have a wordpress site and I'm trying to make a style sheet for mobile devices but it doesn't seem to work. This is the code I used

```
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I used mobilephoneemulator.com to test the site but it doesn't seem to be using the mobile css. What is wrong? if it helps my site is http://www.deliciousmanga.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to mobile.css normally `<link rel="stylesheet" href=".....etc`

Wrap the entire mobile.css stylesheet in this block

`@media screen and (max-device-width: 320px) and (min-width: 0px), (max-width: 320px) {css goes here}`